# How to add -framework IOKit to your makefile to get serial number of the iOS device?

Tags: ios, xcode, iokit

Hi to get serial number of the ios device everyone answering the below code but its showing error io_service_t not found because of i doesn't import iokit framework ? Can any one tell how to add ios kit to xcode project?

Answer (score 2):

You can not get the iOS device serial number, any device identifying numbers have been removed from the SDK by Apple to protect the privacy of the user.